# Replicate iOS 11 Control Center Screen

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I am trying to re-create the iOS 11 control center view. I am not trying to make it functional just yet, but I am trying to get the same styling and I can't manage to pinpoint the way it looks in iOS 11. How do I go about this? Here is what I have so far next to what I would like, without the buttons on the blur view of course. Any tips? Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_5413.PNG"))
view.backgroundColor = .white
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 350, height: 650)

let light = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let lightView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: light)
lightView.layer.masksToBounds = true
lightView.frame = view.frame
lightView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(lightView)

let dark = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)

let darkView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: dark)
darkView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
darkView.layer.masksToBounds = true
darkView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 250, height: 250)
darkView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(darkView)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

[image: What I have][image: What I want to have]

Comment: Instead of frames, maybe try using anchors? Set centerX/centerY to the superview's centerX/centerY? And sure, instead of frame height/width, you'll need to set the subview height/width using auto layout - easily done like the center values. I think you have the UIView piece right - the backgroundColor, radius, and blur - correct. Just change the "frame" thinking to "auto layout".

Comment: Oh hey i'm not too worried about the layout right now ill do that later, Im just trying to get the blur effect to look exactly the same. I guess it's close enough though.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thought you were talking layout because I focused on the word "Center" in your question. :-) `UIBlurEffect` has a select few options - `.light`, `.extraLight`, and `.dark`. I'd say you are "close", maybe even "close enough". If you want better than that - and I've been there - you need to use CoreImage. They have several blur effects, and one of them may look better for you.

Comment: ooh indeed. Core image is wonderful. Ive played with filters quite a bit. Ill look into those blur effects within CI. Thanks!

Comment: I once used a `UIBlurEffect` that seemed to have broken once I added a `UITabController`. That introduced me to CoreImage. I just realized I don't yet have a public GitHub with anything that can help you use CI filters. If you need anything, let me know. I can get something up pretty quickly. One repo I *heavily* recommend is Filterpedia: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia. It's in Swift 2 but (using his work in other blogs) I have it in Swift 3.